# Is there a list of tokens anywhere?

Tags: tokens

Is there a list of tokens that are available anywhere? Is it stored in some db table I haven't seen?

CiviCRM 5.20.2 on Wordpress

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit tricky to answer, because there are three different token processors in CiviCRM.  The Smarty processor, the legacy token processor, and the new `Civi\TokenProcessor` processor.

#### Legacy Processor (aka `CRM_Utils_Token`)

For most messages - quick emails, PDFs, etc. - you're using the legacy token processor.  You can find most of these tokens in [CRM_Core_SelectValues](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/SelectValues.php#L486).  Note that contacts will provide all exportable fields as tokens, minus the ones explicitly excluded in that file.

You can also add tokens via extensions, so this isn't a complete list.  Note that with the legacy token processor, you can only add new contact tokens.

#### TokenProcessor

Currently, TokenProcessor is only available with Scheduled Reminders and Flexmailer.  Work is currently underway to bring TokenProcessor support to the rest of CiviCRM, which will allow you to use more fields, and define custom tokens that are based on contributions/activities/etc.  In the next month or so, I'd expect to see support for TokenProcessor for emails sent with Email API (i.e. CiviRules), along with PDFs/emails generated from activities, with contribution PDFs/emails not far behind.

#### Smarty

Smarty tokens are available only in System Workflow messages, and the tokens vary on a per-template basis.  You can also enable Smarty token processing if you're not using Flexmailer and/or Mosaico by adding `define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1 );` to your `civicrm.settings.php`.

Comment: That is great information to know - I had figured this was something in flux. I am looking for scheduled reminders, specifically the membership stuff, so will dig into the TokenProcessor

Comment: Small update: the new TokenProcessor is used for PDF's from an Activity Search

Answer (score 1):

There's the list in the user guide: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#available-tokens

It should be mostly complete.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be missing the membership. tokens that are used in the TokenProcessor

Comment: I am also missing the contribution tokens in that list.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting the the [Extended tokens extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken) offers some other ones

Comment: The provided link leads to "page not found".

Comment: Try https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken